# Raspberry pi camera pinout

Tags: gpio, camera

Since my disable_camera_led=1/0 does not do anything and searching on forums did not help, I decided to debug it myself.

Since I know disable_camera_led=1/0 turns on/off a pin in GPIO, I want to know what is the Pinout of a camera board, and I will turn this GPIO pin On/Off myself. The only reference pinout picture I found is this:

[image: pri pinout]

from [here](https://components101.com/misc/pi-camera-module).

Now, Using my multimeter I checked the pins, GND connects to GND, 3.3V to 3.3V so the pinout seems right.

I guess the CAM_GPIO is the one I am interested on, but this does not connect to any GPIO pin!

This pin should be connected to a GPIO pin right? Maybe the pinout is not 100% correct?

Or the camera I bought is just a fake imitation of the 'real' rpi camera pinout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the same question on raspberry Pi's forums, [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=312005&p=1866125#p1866125) . @6by9 replied and solved my question.

His reply is:

> Schematics for [v2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/schematics/rpi_SCH_Camera2_2p1.pdf) and [HQ](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/schematics/rpi_SCH_Camera2_2p1.pdf) camera modules are published (off the [camera
> hardware page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/README.md)), as are reduced schematics for [all the versions of Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md)
> (eg [Pi4](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_4b_4p0_reduced.pdf)).
>
> Only the v1 camera module had an LED fitted. v2 and HQ don't. 3rd
> party products will vary.
>
> Pi4 and CM4 no longer connect the line to a controllable GPIO (left
> floating).